# Скачивание видео по url ссылке

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiohttp

Бьюсь третий день, не могу понять, в чем проблема. Вот куски кода бота телеграмм, который должен скачивать видео по url-ссылке с файлообменника (files.fm). Я знаю, что проблема именно в этих кусках кода (использую библиотеку aiohttp):

```
    # Обработчик прикрепления ссылки на видео
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT)
    async def video_url_handler(message: types.Message):
        # Проверяем, что это ссылка на видео (предполагаем, что ссылка содержит "http" и "files.fm")
        video_url = message.text.strip()
        if "https" in video_url and "transfiles.ru" in video_url:
            if message.from_user.id not in user_attachments:
                user_attachments[message.from_user.id] = {}
            # Получаем ссылку на видео из текстового сообщения
            user_attachments[message.from_user.id]["video_url"] = video_url
            await message.reply("Вы приложили ссылку на видео. Нажмите кнопку 'Подтвердить', чтобы продолжить.")
        else:
            await message.reply("Вы не приложили ссылку на видео.")
```

Обработчик выше работает нормально, но вот в следующем обработчике после выполнения загрузки видео в папку на ПК (она создается и нормально функционирует) загружается фото, а видео из 23 МБ загружается только 20КБ. Я прикрепляю ссылку файлообменника с видео, но оно ни в какую не хочет скачиваться. 23 МБ это только для теста, файлы будут от 20 МБ до 100 МБ. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, если этой информации будет достаточно.

```
    # Проверяем, что выбранный тариф был определен и существует в словаре цен
        if chosen_tariff and chosen_tariff in prices_dict:
            # Получаем путь к папке, куда будем сохранять файлы
            full_name = get_user_data(message.from_user.id)[2]  # Получаем полное имя пользователя по его user_id
            user_folder_path = os.path.join("D:\\Programs\\Telegram Bot DFFR", full_name)
            os.makedirs(user_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
    
            # Загрузка фото
            photo_files = user_attachments.get(message.from_user.id, {}).get("photos", [])  # список объектов с фото
            for i, photo in enumerate(photo_files):
                # Загружаем фото
                photo_path = os.path.join(user_folder_path, f"photo_{i}.jpg")
                await photo.download(photo_path)
    
            # Загрузка видео
            video_url = user_attachments.get(message.from_user.id, {}).get("video_url")
            if video_url:
                try:
                    # Загружаем видео
                    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                        async with session.get(video_url) as response:
                            if response.status == 200:
                                video_path = os.path.join(user_folder_path, "video.mp4")
                                with open(video_path, "wb") as f:
                                    while True:
                                        chunk = await response.content.read(1024)
                                        if not chunk:
                                            break
                                        f.write(chunk)
                            else:
                                await message.answer("Не удалось загрузить видео")
    
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Ошибка при загрузке видео: {e}")
                    await message.answer("Произошла ошибка при загрузке видео")
    
            # Удаляем информацию о прикрепленных файлах для данного пользователя, чтобы не скачивать их снова
            del user_attachments[message.from_user.id]
```